# How to get cursor by subscription id?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I specify a particular cursor by its subscription id?

I have 2 subscriptions returning cursors from the same collection but with different selector/modifiers

An example of my use case
I have a template user side-bar that have template subscription to User Collection returning only the current user

this user happens to be in HR and would like to view all users from QA department, another template, filtering by QA department from User Collection

Problem I have now is that by doing a .find() on the client side, it displays all QA users + current user in HR.

It seems that the 2 cursors returning from the same collection are merged together and are indistinguishable even though I have 2 different subscription ids.

Is there a way or workaround where I can specify all values within a particular cursor returned by a specific subscription?

How do I make sibling template subscription work separately, where one template cannot access the cursor returned by another template?

EDIT: to add on
in my use case, i am not stopping the sidebar subscription since i want both templates to be present side-by-side instead

I have reservations about filtering my client side cursor:
1) repeating the same mongo selectors and modifier objects on both the client side and server side seems to violate the Dont-Repeat-Yourself (DRY) guideline, not exactly elegant solution to me

2) say i have a secret field in my collection which i am omitting from my cursor, repeating the mongo modifier on the client side would mean that examining the client side code would reveal the existence of the secret field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a feature of Meteor, not a bug. Multiple subscriptions to the same collection are union-ed. The normal pattern is to always include your query parameters rather than just assuming that `.find({})` will yield a filtered data set. Another common pattern is to stop the current subscription when leaving a route.

Comment: in my use case, i am not stopping the sidebar subscription since i want both templates to be present side-by-side instead
my reservation about your suggestion are:
1) repeating the same mongo selectors and modifier objects on both the client side and server side seems to violate the Dont-Repeat-Yourself (DRY) guideline, not exactly elegant solution to me
2) say i have a secret field in my collection which i am omitting from my cursor, repeating the mongo modifier on the client side would mean that examining the client side code would reveal the existence of the secret field

Comment: You can dehydrate your code by putting your `find()` in a function in `/lib` following [this strategy](http://neo.com/2014/06/24/a-strategy-for-managing-record-retrieval-in-meteor-js/). Stopping your subscriptions is not an option since you are showing two views from the same collection at the same time. Secret fields can always be found by anyone going into console and typing `Collection.findOne()`, you're not fooling anyone by omitting the key from the find on the client.